# Creating New Network

Tags: networking, server, active-directory

This has probably been hashed out somewhere here, but I haven’t found it:
I’m a high school teacher, and assistant tech coordinator. I’m thinking of converting my lab to Ubuntu and currently have some standalone test machines going. I’ve been using some flavor of MS Server for the last 15 years so I’m a bit familiar with that environment, but here are the questions:

1. If I built a blended network with a Windows server and Ubuntu clients, what is the general consensus on systems like Centrify or Likewise (BeyondTrust?).  Any other recommendations?
2. If I made a pure Ubuntu network, is there a guide that could be recommended for setting up an entire Ubuntu network from scratch? Main features I need to operate with are: roaming profiles (so students can use any machine and still have their files), and a way to manage user access and o/s permissions (i.e. limiting their ability to customize their system).
3. In a pure Ubuntu network, what add-ons would be recommended? (A way to create accounts from a csv would be nice.)

I can’t really depend upon any cloud based solutions as bandwidth on the campus is shaky. Within my lab I’m running gigabit whereas the rest of the campus has 100 Mb the often seems to lose its connection. I don’t want to use thin clients as this lab’s main focus is imaging so we have rather large image files along with some minor video editing, and next year I’m planning on adding 3D graphics.

Answer (score -2):

This link might help: [Setting up Ubuntu](http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/it/FAQ/ubuntu_desktop.html)

Comment: I removed the rest of your text - please try to explain how and why that link might help.